# Read and WRITE to MDB file on OS other than Windows

Tags: ms-access

I am using python to read and WRITE an MDB (Microsoft Access Database) file on Windows. This is currently working fine; however, I would now like to run my script on MacOS. Is this possible? The only MDB driver I could find exists here:

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=54920

This obviously doesn't run natively on MacOS. I'm just curious if there is any way to do this at all. Are there any third-party driver providers?